# Change layout of Unity's Project->Assets pane contents to show longer filenames?

Tags: unity

I'm working on a project with assets that have really long filenames. I know about the slider in the lower-right corner of the Project->Assets pane, but THAT slider makes the icons absolutely HUGE & only allows the display of filenames that are slightly longer than the default.

Is there a way to either:

- Get Unity to use a view akin to Windows Explorer's "List" view (small icon on the left, long filename on the right)
- Get Unity to truncate long filenames in the **middle**? For example...

  - Full name: `ExtraordinarilyLongFilename-27a.material`
  - How it displays now: `ExtraordinarilyLongF...`
  - How I'd *like* it to truncate: `ExtraordinarilyL...e-27a`

(the general assumption of a middle-truncated long name being that the last few characters are usually the ones that distinguish between multiple files that all begin with the same prefixes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either change to a Explorer-style layout, or a single-column layout, both of which will allow you to see the full filename.

First, locate the size slider in the bottom right:
[image: Step 1]

And drag it all the way to the left to get your explorer-style display:
[image: Step 2]

Or use a single column layout by pressing the [Hamburger button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button) in the top right of the window and choose One Column Layout, particularly useful if your Project window is oriented more vertically:
[image: Step 3]

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed to know! Thanks!